# Grep finds the word and then stucks (bash)

Tags: grep

I have a loop (while, extracting 2 variables) where I found one command is not working. Even when I put the command in the console directly (subsituting by my own the variable) it gives the result but continue working without any advance.

The command's objective is to find in a big file.gct, in specific in its first three lines, an object obtained from other file and then print the finding and everything before in that line.

If someone know why it stucks and how to fix it or even an alternative that works well in loops and does not demands more RAM's use it would be appreciated.

`head -3 file_2 | grep -E -o ".{0,1000}$variable."`

Kind of an example as how it looks the big file (file_2):

`head -3 file_2`

|   #1.2    |

|   57000   |   17300   |

|Irrelevant|Irrelevant2| DATA-B12-18 | DATA-Y17-72 | DATA-A12-44 | .... |

When I run in the terminal:   `head -3 file_2 | grep -E -o ".{0,1000}DATA-B12-18"`

the output is:
`Irrelevant   Irrelevant2  DATA-B12-18` and then stacks.

Comment: Is `head -3 file_2` working as expected?

Comment: Maybe `head -n 3 file_2 | grep -E -o ".{0,1000}$variable."`?

Comment: Could `$variable` contain metacharacters?  Give us some example data.

Comment: `head -3 file_2` returns the value expected

Comment: `head -3 file_2 | cut -c1-"DATA-B12-18"` --> cut: invalid byte/character position «DATA-B12-18»

Comment: oops sorry, embarassing mistake on my part wrt `cut` suggestion..

Comment: What you describe is impossible and `grep -E -o ".{0,1000}DATA-B12-18"` on `|Irrelevant|Irrelevant2| DATA-B12-18 | DATA-Y17-72 | DATA-A12-44 | .... |` **cannot** output `Irrelevant   Irrelevant2  DATA-B12-18` since grep doesn't convert `|`s to spaces. Please [edit] you question to copy/paste from your terminal the output of `head -3 file_2 | cat -Ev` and the output of `head -3 file_2 | grep -E -o ".{0,1000}DATA-B12-18" | cat -Ev` followed by you hitting the return key to see if your prompt reappears.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for how to properly format your input and output text blocks.